# Volume decreases as soon as I start Jack

Tags: sound, jack, audio-jack

I am using Reaper and other music software on Ubuntu 23.04 that require Jack. As long as my PulseAudio is active, I hear music at a high (normal) volume. As soon as I start Jack, the volume drops, and I hear a very low output.

Thing is that I cannot change the output of Jack or the "System". Anybody knows how to solve this issue?

---

I leave this temporary note for future users: I just understood that Jack *may* automatically set the PulseAudio volume as its own volume. Because, when I put my normal sound at MAX and *then* start Jack, the volume is actually ok. So, in case, remember: set the max volume *before* starting Jack.